# How to plot one complex number in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, complex-numbers

Here are my tries:

First plot equations. This is what I know how to do.

```
Plot[{Re[Sqrt[a]], Im[Sqrt[a]]}, {a, -3, 6}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "y"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

Then plot a single point. I keep getting errors?

```
complex[x_] = a + I b
a + I b

a = 3; b = 2;
complex[x]
3 + 2 I

Plot[complex[x]]
Plot::argr: Plot called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected.

Plot[{Re[a], Im[b]}, {a, 3, 3}, {b, 2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "y"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red}]
Plot::nonopt: Options expected (instead of {b,2,2}) beyond position 2 in 
An option must be a rule or a list of rules.
```

Any suggestions?
MM

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered `Plot` is intended for plotting continuous functions. One option for plotting a single number in the complex plane would be to write something like

```
z1 = 3 + 4 I
```

and then

```
ListPlot[{{Re[z1], Im[z1]}}]
```

`ListPlot` is the function for plotting lists of points; here the list has only 1 entry, formed from the components of the complex number `z1`.  I expect you can turn this into a function to avoid having to destructure the complex number by hand.

As ever with Mathematica, there is a whole armoury of other approaches you could employ, but this one seems about the simplest.  For future reference, Mathematica has its own existence in the Stack Exchange universe, at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Incidentally, while I'm writing, don't mess about with your own definition of `complex`.  Enter the first expression above, then type `Head[z1]` and see what is returned.  In case it is not immediately obvious Mathematica understands `I` to be the imaginary unit `Sqrt[-1]`.  Complex numbers are first-class citizens in Mathematica not an afterthought as in so many concept-poor programming languages.

Comment: Mark, This code puts both the real and imaginary parts of the equation as "y" values. It plots (1,3) and (2,4). ListPlot uses 1,2,3,... as x values in the pair, (x,y). MM